# Create Android Wear application with Xamarin

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to start a new Android Wear project with Xamarin, but when I try to create a new project with Visual Studio **for Mac** I can't find the Android Wear template.
Am I Missing something?

This is my wizard:
[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to create Android Wear application on Visual Studio for Mac **on macOS High Sierra**:

- create a blank solution (*new project -> miscellanous -> blacn solution*)
- then right *click on the solution -> add project -> Android -> Wear*

Answer (score 1):

On what version and update channel are you?
I have a template available with the current version on stable channel.
[image]

Comment: I'm also on the stable channel.
I'm using MacOs High Sierra

Comment: I am on Sierra but that shouldn't be the cause.